# Vertical line not centered between columns using ruledtabular

Tags: revtex

How do I get the vertical line in the middle of the columns while using `ruledtabular`, not like this?

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2} 
\begin{document}
\begin{ruledtabular} 
\begin{tabular}{c|c} 
    a & b \\
    aaaaa & bbbbb \\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Simple answers while maintaining the use of `ruledtabular` and the house style (full width tables), that will be accepted by journal editors preferred :)

Comment: Did you try with `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} ... \end{tabularx}`?

Comment: My impression is that the house style doesn't want vertical rules.

Comment: @Bernard: I tried it just now and the first column took up the whole linewidth - I'm not sure if `tabularx` and `ruledtabular` behave well together. I'd prefer a `tabular` solution if possible.

Comment: @egreg: I suspect that may be the answer.

Comment: In this case, maybe trying `*{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\0.5\arrayrulewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\0.5\arrayrulewidth}}`   for the table preamble would work?

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you. Yes for this MWE (but with `\0` replaced by `0`), your suggestion makes each column half of the page width. However the actual table has seven columns of varying widths, so I can't use `0.5\linewidth`. I'm thinking there is no `ruledtabular` simple solution, and I'll just abandon the idea and increase `\setlength{\tabcolsep}` on a regular table.